# Ng-class with condition in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have the below popup where the user can encode item information.

[image]

My requirement is that, when `Foreign Currency` and `Conversion Rate` are both have values, it should multiply `Foreign Currency * Conversion Rate` to get the `Amount`. And when both `Foreign Currency` and `Conversion Rate` are 0, then `Amount` field should accept user input.

Currently, I have the below HTML.

```
<div class="form-group" show-errors>
<label for="foreignCurrency" class="control-label col-md-3 text-muted">Foreign Currency</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-dollar fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;</span>
        <input type="number" id="foreignCurrency" name="foreignCurrency" class="form-control" placeholder="Foreign Currency" ng-model="vm.newItem.newItemEnt.ForeignCurrency" value="{{vm.newItem.newItemEnt.ForeignCurrency || 0}}" min="0" />
    </div>
    <p class="help-block" ng-if="perksFrm.foreignCurrency.$error.min">The minimum foreign currency value is 0</p>
</div>
```

```
<div class="form-group" show-errors>
<label for="convRate" class="control-label col-md-3 text-muted">Conversion Rate</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-money"></i></span>
        <input type="number" id="convRate" name="convRate" class="form-control" placeholder="Conversion Rate" ng-model="vm.newItem.newItemEnt.ConversionRate" ng-required="vm.newItem.newItemEnt.ForeignCurrency" value="{{vm.newItem.newItemEnt.ConversionRate || 0}}" min="0" />
    </div>
    <p class="help-block" ng-if="perksFrm.convRate.$error.required">The conversion rate is required</p>
    <p class="help-block" ng-if="perksFrm.convRate.$error.min">The minimum conversion rate is 0</p>
</div>
```

```
<div class="form-group" show-errors>
<label for="amount" class="control-label col-md-3 text-muted">Amount</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-money"></i></span>
        <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" ng-model="vm.newItem.newItemEnt.Amount" required />
    </div>
    <p class="help-block" ng-if="perksFrm.amount.$error.required">The first name is required</p>
</div>
```

In `Amount` html, I can do it like this `{{vm.newItem.newItemEnt.ForeignCurrency * vm.newItem.newItemEnt.ConversionRate}}`. But, what if they have a 0 value and my requirement is to accept the user input from `Amount` textbox.

Any advise to achieve my requirements?

TIA

Comment: Given you answer, according to my understanding, please let me know is what you are looking for. if anything else let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirment, I tried to provide you answer.

Please find Code for this, also JS fiddle demo.

HTML

```
<style>
    .error{
        border-color:red;
    }
</style>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">Foreign Currency</div>
        <div class="col-lg-2"><input type="number" ng-model="FCurrency" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">Rate</div>
        <div class="col-lg-2"><input type="number" ng-model="Rate" /></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">Amount</div>
        <div class="col-lg-2"><input  ng-class="{error : RateAmount <= 0}" ng-disabled="isAmountDisable"
                                      type="number" ng-model="RateAmount" /></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.RateAmount = 0;
    $scope.isAmountDisable = false;

    function setRateAmount() {
        if ($scope.FCurrency > 0 && $scope.Rate > 0) {
            $scope.RateAmount = ($scope.FCurrency * $scope.Rate);
            $scope.isAmountDisable = true;
        }
        else {
            $scope.RateAmount = 0;
            $scope.isAmountDisable = false;
        }
    }
    $scope.$watch('FCurrency', function (newval, oldval) {
        setRateAmount();
    });

    $scope.$watch('Rate', function (newval, oldval) {
        setRateAmount();

    });


});
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/12647/)

Comment: Thanks for the code and effort creating the sample in JS Fiddle, it worked well!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use ng-change on `foreignCurrency` and `convRate` input.

when those input change you can calcul your amount value and disable it.

if they are both 0, you can enable it.

Something like this :

```
function change() {
   var foreignCurrency = vm.newItem.newItemEnt.ForeignCurrency;
   var conversionRate = vm.newItem.newItemEnt.ConversionRate;

 if (foreignCurrency === 0 && conversionRate === 0) {
    vm.enableAmout = true;
 } else {
    vm.enableAmout = false;
    vm.vm.newItem.newItemEnt.Amount = foreignCurrency * conversionRate;
  }
}
```